# How to evaluate a logical expression in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

let's say I have a database table "ACCOUNTS" where it only has 3 fields:

1. ACCOUNT_NUMBER (BIGINT)
2. CREDIT (BIGINT)
3. DEBIT (BIGINT)

And I simply want to make a query that will show only two columns:

1. ACCOUNT_NUMBER (BIGINT)
2. "BALANCED" (A boolean value. True if Credit == Debit, false otherwise)

How do I make such a query?

I tried using the equal operator (=) but it doesn't accept it

```
SELECT 
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
    CREDIT = DEBIT as "BALANCED"
FROM ACCOUNTS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Boolean datatype in Oracle's SQL, so you'll have to *live* with its string (or numeric) representation, such as

```
select account_number,
       case when credit = debit then 'true'
            else 'false'
       end as balanced
from accounts
```

Comment: I see! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` like this:

```
SELECT 
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
    CASE CREDIT WHEN 'DEBIT' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END AS "BALANCED"
FROM ACCOUNTS;
```

If it does not fit 0 and 1, change to other values, but this is logic how to do it.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Menas then please check my answer. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Marko, that won't work properly. You're comparing credit value (which is a number, represents some *money*) to a string (word DEBIT enclosed into single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

you can return bit in SQL instead of Boolean. Use case statement for this.

-- For SQL Server
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CAST(CASE WHEN DEBIT =CREDIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) Balanced FROM ACCOUNTS;

-- For Oracle
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CASE WHEN DEBIT =CREDIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Balanced FROM ACCOUNTS;